# keras: Different accuracy score between keras.model.evaluate and sklearn.accuracy_score

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, keras

I have a `keras` model (called `model`).

```py
model.compile(
    loss='binary_crossentropy',
    optimizer='adam',
    metrics=['accuracy'],
)
model.fit(
    X_train,
    Y_train,
    batch_size=batch_size,
    epochs=nb_epoch,
    validation_data=(X_test, Y_test),
)
score, acc = model.evaluate(X_test, Y_test, batch_size=batch_size)
```

and

```py
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
preds = model.predict_classes(X_test, verbose=0)
print('prediction  accuracy: ', accuracy_score(y_test, preds))
```

The problem here is that the two accuracy scores are different. I have no idea how can it is possible because they are calculated based on the same data.

Could you give me some hints?

---

**Update**

Furthermore, I saw a huge difference on `val_acc` while training and the `accuracy` in the final step. Even I use the same test set for training and evaluation.

Here is my training process:

```
Epoch 16/20
16256/16256 [==============================] - 3s - loss: 0.1011 - acc: 0.9604 - val_loss: 0.1191 - val_acc: 0.9545
Epoch 17/20
16256/16256 [==============================] - 4s - loss: 0.0986 - acc: 0.9615 - val_loss: 0.1224 - val_acc: 0.9536
Epoch 18/20
16256/16256 [==============================] - 3s - loss: 0.0965 - acc: 0.9622 - val_loss: 0.1197 - val_acc: 0.9550
Epoch 19/20
16256/16256 [==============================] - 3s - loss: 0.0946 - acc: 0.9631 - val_loss: 0.1213 - val_acc: 0.9542
Epoch 20/20
16256/16256 [==============================] - 3s - loss: 0.0929 - acc: 0.9634 - val_loss: 0.1288 - val_acc: 0.9519
```

the `val_acc` reaches to 0.95.

But when I do:

```py
preds = model.predict_classes(X_test, verbose=0)
print('prediction 8 accuracy: ', accuracy_score(test['Rating'], preds+1))
```

The accuracy score is only `0.68`.

I note that `Y_test` and `y_test` are the same.

```py
Y_test = np_utils.to_categorical(y_test, nb_classes)
```

Comment: How much different are they? What's your model definition?

Comment: my model is a LSTM model. they are quite different: 0.94 ~ 0.63.

Comment: You still need to provide a full model definition in python, including how you compile the model.